# How to slide an element in onClick event and then slide that element back to original position when another element is clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Im using jQuery animate() to handle the effects. The problem that Im running into is that either the div slides on and off again w/o a pause or the element continues to slide to the left.

What I've tried:

```
var inView;
$('.contentBox').click(function(e){
 inView = false;
 var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
 if(inView == false){
    $('.details div').eq(tmp_div).show().animate({"left": "+=4000"}, "slow");
    inView = true;

 }
 if(inView == true){
     $('.details div').eq(tmp_div).show().animate({"left": "-=4000"}, "slow");
             inView = false;
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs an `if else` cuz currently it will fire both sets of animation. Also since the var is set in the click function it will always be false. You want it to run off two element clicks so you need two click events most likely. So something like this might work for you although it is hard to figure with the limited description provided.

```
var inView = false;
$('#element1').click(function(e){
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     if(inView == false){
        $('.details div').eq(tmp_div).show().animate({"left": "+=4000"}, "slow");
        inView = true;

     }
});
$('#element2').click(function(e){
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     if(inView == true){
         $('.details div').eq(tmp_div).show().animate({"left": "-=4000"}, "slow");
         inView = false;
     }
});
```